# Migrating Redmine plugin to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redmine-plugins

I am trying to run [Time Tracker plugin](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_time_tracker) with Redmine 2.0.1 on Bitnami Stack.
I found that it's imcompatible with Redmine 2.* but it couldn't stop me.
So, I placed this plugin in `../redmine/htdocs/plugins/redmine_time_tracker`, migrated it with `rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV=production`, changed routes to Rails 3 style in `redmine_time_tracker/config/routes.rb` and renamed all files in `redmine_time_tracker/app/views` from *.rhtml to *.html.erb. After another Redmine's restart I rested against the wall. There is an error message in Redmine's production.log:

```
Started GET "/redmine" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Jun 12 22:36:05 +0400 2012
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/base (9.5ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_time_tracker/app/views/time_trackers/_embed_menu.html.erb (203.0ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_time_tracker/app/views/time_trackers/_update_menu.html.erb (203.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 252ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `time_tracker_for' for #<#<Class:0x7f5efb458e48>:0x7f5efb322290>):
    1: <% time_tracker = time_tracker_for(User.current) %>
    2: <% if !time_tracker.nil? %>
    3:     <% if time_tracker.paused %>
    4:         <%# A time tracker is in pause, display the tracked issue, the time spent and the resume/stop actions %>
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:110:in `send'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:110:in `view_layouts_base_body_bottom'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `send'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `each'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in `tap'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in `call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:151:in `call_hook'
  app/views/layouts/base.html.erb:80:in `_app_views_layouts_base_html_erb___1317325009_70022959536540'
```

`time_tracker_for` helper is placed in `redmine_time_tracker/app/helpers/application_helper.rb` and I think it should be loaded automatically according to "Plugin constructor" in `redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/plugin.rb`.

I am new to Ruby and Rails and need some directions to continue fight this magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally Solved.

I found here : http://www.redmine.org/boards/3/topics/31445
the answer (after reading almost anything I found about plugins in redmine and engines in rails3)

> ### Extending default helpers and controllers
>
> In Redmine versions prior to 2.0.0 all plugins were in vendor/plugins
>   folder and because of that Rails automatically loaded and added all
>   files inside app/controllers, app/helpers, app/models, etc folders.
>
> This approach allowed to extend existing controllers and helpers by
>   simply adding appropriate files and methods to the plugin' folders.
>   For example, if we have to add method get_list_of_projects to
>   SettingsHelper we can simply create file named settings_helper.rb in
>   app/helpers folder of the plugin. Redmine 2.x moved plugins to plugins
>   folder in application's root and because of that method described
>   above does not work at all. So we have to use patching and override
>   mechanisms described above to make things work.

In the link is explained how to make the mentioned patching mechanism.

I implemented that patch for the time_tracker plugin for redmine and is working.
The code is in a github fork
https://github.com/martinllanos/redmine_time_tracker

I hope it helps.
Any questions ask here :)

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem, migrating time tracker plugin to be used on Redmine 2.

I have been searching on the web and while I still couldn't fix it I found some usefull info that i think is the way to solve this.

The first part is redmine plugins are basically Rails engines
http://www.redmine.org/boards/3/topics/13419

so I started googling about that.

I found two posts on ruby-forum that talk about the problem of overriding the ApplicationHelper from the Application, with the ApplicationHelper from the plugin.
They give several methods of tring to solve this , but i still haven't test it (I'm trying to understand the code)

Here are the posts.

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/211017

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1455297

If you get a concrete/clear answer from there it would be great :)

Any news from my side will be posted.